# Is this a dialect of German or incorrect usage of the language?

Tags: dialect

Recently, in our school we've had some foreign exchange students over from Switzerland, Austria and Germany. I found a notebook one of them was using and on it was some language, which I thought, looked maybe like some kind of dialect of German:

> "Ha! Heves Gechen Bine"

is what the writing says. Although the 'v' could be an 'r', I'm not sure.
If anybody has any ideas, that would be great.

Comment: If you omit the h in and change e to a, then it's Turkish :D Though it might not be meaningful.

Comment: It is uncommon to write in dialect. In school you learn only to write 'High German' (with some variants in Austria and Switzerland).

Comment: It's not too uncommon to write in dialect in Switzerland, especially among teenagers in informal communication (like SMS/text or emails). The above quote doesn't parse in Swiss German though. Why don't you just ask the exchange students?

Comment: That does seem the easier option. I just thought I'd give you all a glance first, see if any lightbulbs lit up. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I am also friends with some of the Swiss exchanges and they do indeed write in their dialect.

Comment: Bine is sometimes used as short form of *Sabine*. The other words don't sound anything I've ever heard in an Austrian or Swiss dialect.

Comment: It is definitely not standard german and it is definitely not any austrian dialect. And I'm pretty shure that it is no swiss dialect. To me it sounds more like danish or dutch.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure it's not some Austrian or Swiss dialect.

Some theories given the few words:

1. It's English

   > Ha! Here(')s Gechen Bine.

   The author omitted the apostrophe and "Gechen Bine" could be a proper name. People from Bavaria or Austria sometimes use the *last name / first name* word order.
2. It's Turkish

   The word *heves* means *passion* or *eagerness* in Turkish. The other words could be a name in this case too.

Comment: *"Gechen"* could also stand for [geçen](http://tr.thefreedictionary.com/ge%C3%A7en) = vergangen, verflossen - I vote for Turkish! Translated to German: *"Ha! Bine hat Schluss gemacht."*

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound anything like austrian-german or german-german. Could however be Schweizerdeutsch from Switzerland, which is quite different.

Comment: It doesn't sound Swiss German at all.

Answer (score 0):

It could be `Romansh`, a language which is spoken in parts of Switzerland.

Comment: What makes you think this could be Romansh? What would it translate to?